# Downloading CSV file from website/server with Python 3.X

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, urllib

Programming beginner here. So for my very first project I was able to make a quick python script that downloaded files from this website: 
http://www.wesm.ph/inner.php/downloads/market_prices_&_schedules

I noticed that the link address of the to-be-downloaded file 
followed a pattern.
(http://wesm.ph/admin/downloads/download.php?download=../csv/mpas/XXXXX/XXXX.csv)

With some string concatenation and using the datetime module, I was able to create the HTML string of the csv file. After which, I just would use the:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(HTMLlink).read()
```

and save it with something like:

```
with open('output.csv', "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(fullList)
```

It used to work - now it doesn't. I noticed however whenever I clicked the 'Generate Report' button and THEN run the script, the script would generate the output file. I'm not sure why this works. Is there a way to send a request to their server to generate the actual file? Which module, or commands should I use?

Comment: _It used to work_ do you mean in Python 2 it used to work?

Comment: This is because when you click `Generate report` the website creates the file, which your script is able to download then. Probably, after a while website removes these generated reports. What you need to do is to modigy your script so that it first submits a form, then extracts url to a generated report and finally downloads it.

Comment: @Caridorc to clarify: it used to work like 5 days ago using python 3.X

Comment: @vrs  Ok, I think I get what you mean. I'll have to request the data before running the script that I made. Sorry, I'm fairly new to this but which module/command will allow me to request from said website?

Comment: @slsilv Go ahead with `urllib` or `requests`, they both have methods to make GET and POSt requests. Then you may also use `BeautifulSoup` to get url of the csv file. Google for it. StackOverflow is full of threads about these modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely those files are only temporarily stored on that webserver after you click 'Generate Report'.

In order to grenerate new ones, there might even be a check (in JavaScript or using Cookies, Session-ID), to see if the generation of the new link/file is asked from a human, or a bot.

You might also want to check the HTTP return code (or even the full returned headers to see what exactly the server is answering).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think you helped me figure it out. I checked what the link was returning and found an HTML link that essentially makes the request. With some quick manipulations I think I'll be able to figure this out.